# Xcode 10.3 is crashing when I try to run test suite in macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos-catalina, xcode10.3

I have tried to explore macOS Catalina 10.15 beta. When I try to run my test suites in Xcode 10.3 it crashes. Is there any fix that could help to make a workaround?